# Как посчитать количество вхождений (value_counts) в Pandas по второму элементу списка из аттрибута?

Tags: python, pandas

Имеется Pandas DataFrame, состоящий из одного аттрибута, где каждое значение - список из двух элементов. Как можно применить функцию `value_counts()` к каждому второму значению списка элементов? То-есть я хочу узнать сколько одинаковых фамилий присутствует в наборе данных.

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Срезы разные пробовал, функции строк, не получается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: сделайте колонку фамилий. и тогда все будет просто

Comment: @splash58, да, это как вариант, но всё же делать лишние операции думаю плохая идея.

Comment: тогда вам придется делать цикл и считать самому - это при использовании pandas еще худщая идея

Comment: Покажите воспроизводимый пример данных. А если ещё раз `str.split` применить? А если `str.extract` попробовать?

Answer (score 2):

Можно c помощью [pandas.Series.str.get](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html)  "извлечь элемент из списков, кортежей, dict или строк в каждом элементе в серии/индексе". Полная запись - `.str.get(i)`, сокращенная `.str[i]`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': [['John','Smith'],['Sarah','Connor'],['John','Connor']]})
print(df.name.str[1].value_counts())
```

```
Connor    2
Smith     1
Name: name, dtype: int64
```